# Rails: Calling a Javascript function at the end of the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a js file in my assets/javascripts/ directory. This file is being picked up by rails correctly ( I can see it in firebug when I check the page's `head` tag)

And I'm calling a function from this js file in my **application.js** as follows:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

$(window).load(function(){
    Boxlayout.init();
});
```

I read on SO somewhere that the `init()` functions must be called with `.load` function so that they are called after the DOM is loaded.

**But here the javascript is not working.**

On the contrary when I explicitly include the js file with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "file.js" %>
```

**at the bottom of the page** and call the same `init` function from application.js the javascript works fine.

I don't want to explicitly include the file. ( want to do it the rails way). So how do I do it with the first method?

**EDIT**

Using **Rails 3.2.14** (No Turbolinks).

Also the Javascript is **not working on Heroku** though it works fine locally.

Comment: Show your application.js file, please

Comment: As an aside, [`.load(…)`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) was deprecated in jQuery 1.8; you should be using [`.on("load", …)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Are you using turbolinks? If so, $(window).load will not be called. Turbolinks replace the body of the page, which is why your script is run when you embed it in the body.

Comment: @superluminary Nope. I'm using Rails 3.2.14 and no turbolinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

into

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: Note that this means something different. `load` would wait until all images and CSS finish downloading, while `ready` runs as soon as the HTML has been downloaded and the DOM has been loaded into memory.

Comment: That still doesn't work when I remove the `<%= include_tag %>` for the js file

Comment: @RoryO'Kane I want to use the `.load` function. want to exceute the js after all css has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have //= require_tree . in application.js Just will try create new file *.js in assets/javascripts/ directory, and append your code there.

Comment: So what? I know that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a turbolinks issue.

Turbolinks swap out the body of the page via AJAX when you click a link but leave the head intact. Because the CSS and JavaScript are only downloaded and parsed at the start of a browsing session you get a significant speed boost.

The downside is that your jQuery load events will not be triggered. This explains why your script is executing when you embed it in the body of the page, but not when it is correctly placed in the head.

Try including the jQuery turbolinks gem. This will trigger the expected jQuery events when a turbolink is activated.

https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: I'm not using Turbolinks.